# CSS: Shadow overlay

Tags: css

I am trying to add a shadow overlay behind the dialog box. I ran into an issue that I don't quite know how to fix.

This is the code I have: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kxbP4/)

There is the div with class shadowDialog.

```
.shadowDialog {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 665;
    //display: none;
}
```

It should cover the whole space. However, it covers only the space that I can see when I open the dialog and not the rest of the space that I can scroll to (in the downside).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `position: fixed` instead.

Comment: Just a hint for the future: When you make a JSFiddle, make sure you reduce it to the absolute minimum needed to show the problem. I spent a lot of time working out what everything did, before taking a shot in the dark.